# Powershell reporting error on the wrong line

Tags: powershell

My script threw an InvokeMethodOnNull error. Usually debugging this is pretty straightforward but because Powershell reported the error on the wrong line of code, it sent me on the wrong path and I lost a day !

The part of my code that threw the error was

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
<snip>
    #CM
    CmLastMdeConnection  = if ($cmDevice.ATPLastConnected) { Get-Date -Date $cmDevice.ATPLastConnected -Format 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' } else { $null }
    # AD
    AdDomain             = $adDevice.CanonicalName.Split('/')[0]
<snip>
}
```

The InvokeMethodOnNull error happens because `$adDevice` is `$null`, but PS5.1 and 7.2 reported the error on the previous line:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\...\DeviceReport_v3.ps1:903 char:61
+ ... onnected) { Get-Date -Date $cmDevice.ATPLastConnected -Format 'dd-MMM ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have no idea why it did that, and I wasn't able to find explanations with Google Search.

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the issue. The code you've posted isn't valid PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed seeing a *bug*, present in both *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to at least v7.3.6 (the current version as of this writing):

If an error occurs during construction of a `[pscustomobject]` based on a (multiline) *literal*:

- It is the line of the (last) *preceding* entry (property) that initializes a property with a *command* (or command *pipeline*) that is mistakenly reported as the offending line, even if a later, *expression-based* entry causes the actual, invariably *statement-terminating* error.
- If no *commands* are among the entry values, the error message invariably reports the *first* line as the offending one.

See ways to reproduce these problems below.

Note:

- The problems analogously apply to *single-line* `[pscustomobject]` literals (with entries separated with `;`), in which case it is the *wrong part of the line* / the *entire line* that is underlined as the offending part.
- The problematic behaviors have been reported in [GitHub issue #20013](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20013).

---

To reproduce the first problem:

```bash
[pscustomObject] @{                            # 1
  # Comment lines have no bearing on the bug.  # 2
  # This line causes the problem, because it   # 3
  # contains a *command* (pipeline)            # 4
  UnrelatedPreviousLineWithCommand = Get-Date  # 5
  # A line with an *expression* has no bearing # 6
  # on the bug.                                # 7
  UnrelatedPreviousLineWithExpression = 42     # 8
  OffendingLine          = $null.ThisFails()   # 9
}                                              # 10
```

Output (in PowerShell 7.3.6) - note how the unrelated line with the *command*-based property is mistakenly reported:

```bash
Line |
   5 |    UnrelatedPreviousLineWithCommand = Get-Date  # 5
     |                                       ~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

---

To reproduce the second problem:

```bash
[pscustomObject] @{                                # 1
  # Comment lines have no bearing on the behavior. # 2
  # A failing *expression*, in the absence of      # 3
  # entries initialized with *commands*, is never  # 4
  # reported by its specific line.                 # 5 
  SomeExpression = 1 / 0                           # 6
}                                                  # 7
```

Output (in PowerShell 7.3.6) - note how the *first* line is reported as the offending one:

```bash
Line |
   1 |  [pscustomObject] @{                                # 1
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Attempted to divide by zero.
```